# Display Opened Document's Path at Startup in NSPathControl object 

Tags: cocoa

My project is a doc based application. I'd like to use an `NSPathControl` object to display the path of the opened document at startup.

I'd insert the code here:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)windowController
```

Can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an outlet to the path control and you are calling this from your NSDocument subclass, you can just do this:

```
[pathControl setURL:[self fileURL]];
```

If you are calling this from your NSWindowController subclass then of course it would look like this:

```
[pathControl setURL:[[self document] fileURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three examples listed in the documentation for [NSPathControl](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Could you be more specific about the problem you're having?